# divide rectangle in random sized smaller rectangles

Tags: processing, divide-and-conquer, kdtree

Im doing an art project where i really need to be able to divide a rectangle in a random way.
Ive have been searching alot for this but have not found anything i really can implement in proccesing. The idea is after, reading this thread [Break up a square or rectangle into a large number of randomly sized squares or rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754307/break-up-a-square-or-rectangle-into-a-large-number-of-randomly-sized-squares-or)
to use a KD-tree or an divide conquer algorithm. I only just learned how a basic Binary Tree works so im a bit lost how to implement this in proccesing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1115849) (p5js) sketch divides a rectangular plane in random sized smaller rectangles and seems suitable for your need.

The sketch slices (either horizontally or vertically) the plane recursively until a "slice limit" is reached for each recursive call, upon which a rectangle is returned.

I ported the sketch from js to Java Processing [here](https://github.com/micycle1/PGS/blob/master/src/main/java/micycle/pgs/commons/RectangularSubdivision.java). In fact, it can be easily called from the parent project (PGS) with:

`PShape division = PGS_Tiling.rectSubdivsion(double width, double height, int maxDepth);`

[image]