# How can i fill a square with randomly sized squares and rectangles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i need to know how i can go about filling an area with randomly sized rectangles and squares - like this for instance:
[image]

I already have a partially working demo however it has alot of instances in where it will not work and ontop of this it requires alot of manual checks which isn't the easiest thing to program nor is it efficient.

Ontop of the challenge at hand i'd like to also avoid using methods that require checking collision such as using an attached RigidBody2D or a Ray cast as i'm working with ui and would like to simply generate a table of locations and sizes for easier access (however if this is unavoidable i understand and please do still share your answer if this is the case)

I was hoping to simulate it in the sense of a table where you can merge cells together but i'm uncertain how this is achievable - if at all.

Thankyou in advance! :)

Edit:

In relation to UnholySheep's comment i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754307/break-up-a-square-or-rectangle-into-a-large-number-of-randomly-sized-squares-or). The Kd-Tree looks promising but (correct me if i'm wrong) i don't believe it can be immplemented in csharp without programming out of scope and i think it literally draws squares as opposed to implements gameobjects or Rect objects with a size and position.

Furthermore there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916121/how-to-fill-a-square-with-smaller-squares-rectangles) thread but again it mentions using a Kd-Tree or methods which i want to avoid or as Brian said using a merge method which i don't think is achieavable in unity without programming an entire table module which is out of scope again. Additionally someone mentioned using a spiral which albeit is an interesting approach it wouldn't result in the randomness i want to achieve.

To clarify i am looking for a fairly simple algorithm - i don't believe a Kd-tree fits this but for anyone else this may be an option as there are [unity modules for this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=kdtree%20unity).

Comment: Just a side note - i am aware this question has already been asked more than once but i plee to you mods don't remove it as these questions have been answered in scenarios not relating to unity - thankyou ;)

Comment: If you already found answers to this problem you should link to them in your question and explain the problem you have with adapting them to Unity specific code

Comment: Gotcha! gimme a sec...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "out of scope" - out of what scope? What are your restrictions that prevent a Kd-Tree from being a good solution?

Comment: Oh right sorry! thats unclear (it's late at night over here i do apoligise) - a kd-tree would involve installing an entirely new module which i want to avoid as i want to stick to vanilla unity (i.e not adding any more dependencies and being able to program it myself)

Comment: "would require installing a new module" - well no, you can just implement it yourself. There is nothing stopping you from doing that, the code isn't that long. And you already have similar implementations in the answers you linked yourself in the question

Comment: Not to sound blunt but i just had a look at a Kd-tree implementation in unity and it exceeds 300 lines and 2 files - that seems a bit excessive to me given i'm only going to generate this table of randomly sized rectangles once (https://github.com/viliwonka/KDTree) ?

Surely there's a simpler way?

Comment: That github repo is for a 3D Kd-Tree with a bunch of extra features that you don't need(?). Please read up on the theory and implementation of Kd-Trees (e.g.: on Wikipedia), they are really not that hard to implement

Comment: * facepalm * ah extremely sorry dude didn't even twig that! thanks a ton for putting up with me being silly - need to get some sleep - again cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a challange, plus writing code that perfectly produces the image takes a lot of time and patience. But here I wrote code that puts a field of all kinds of letters in a 2D array. As long as this array is empty it will allow itself to fill them with random rectangles.

```cs
public enum squareType { none, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, Y, W, X, Z }

public squareType[,] cases = new squareType[4,4];
public void Start()
{
    var lengthX = cases.GetLength(0);
    var lengthY = cases.GetLength(1);
    
    var index = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthX; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < lengthY; j++)
        {
            if (cases[i,j] != squareType.none) continue;

            var randomX = Random.Range(i, Mathf.Min(i+3, lengthX)); 
            var randomY = Random.Range(j, Mathf.Min(j+3, lengthY));
            
            var color = (squareType) Enum.ToObject(typeof(squareType), ++index);
            
            for (var x = i; x <= randomX; x++)
            {
                for (var y = j; y <= randomY; y++) cases[x, y] = color;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Debug table
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthX; i++)
    {
        var xField = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < lengthY; j++) xField += " | " + cases[i, j];
        Debug.Log(xField);
    }
}
```

### Example Result 4x4:

[image]

### Example Result 6x6:

[image]

Comment: Oh, also if it isn't too much trouble do you mind explaining to me how the code works? - i have a rough idea in that the +3 in the Random.Range is used to determine the random size of shapes and lowering it to 0 results in an ordered list of the enums. Furthermore `color` is used to fill the array with the enums depending on the `index` variable which is incremented each loop using `++index` - however i'm still a bit stuck on why you use `if (cases[i,j] != squareType.none) continue;` and why `none` is defined at the start of the enum list. Thankyou!

Comment: @Bobbymcbobface I have to say welcome to stack overflow and don't worry too much about downvotes, I'm sure most members here have experienced it. This rule is due to the fact that the link is not considered as internal content and should not be the answer itself, of course, if it is accompanied by an answer, there is no problem.

Comment: @Bobbymcbobface The reason for using `== squareType.none` is to prevent incomplete rectangles (such as those in Tetris). For example, if a house builds a six-piece rectangle and the house below wants to take 2 parts of the rectangle, since the other house of the enums is none. Construction of the rectangle stops.

Comment: Haya @KiynL it's been a while - i've been playing around with your code for some time now to use it in my game (and doing other things of course ;) ) and i came across a problem - when you use `== squareType.none` tetris pieces can still be generated - not sure if you'll get this message but as for future users i'll comment (hopefully) if i find a solution.

Also if you do manage to respond is it ok if you explain to me how the `RandomX` and `RandomY` work? - i'm in understanding that there used to generate the shapes but i'm stuck as to why you use `i+3` - and specifically the number `3`?